# Comparing the final pressures/volumes/temperatures of a reversible and irreversible adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, adiabatic

Consider $2$ ideal and identical gases $A$ and $B$ which are at the same initial state of ($P_1$,$V_1$,$T_1$).

$A$ is taken through a reversible adiabatic process and $B$ through an irreversible adibatic process. Since both a reversible and irreversible adiabatic process can't occur between the same initial and final equilibrium states, compare:-

a)Their final volumes and temperatures if their final pressures are the same

b)Their final pressures and temperatures if their final volumes are the same

c)Their final pressures and volumes if their final temperatures are the same

I have found a method by comparing $W_{rev}$ and $W_{irrev}$ but it is too tedious.Although, comparing $W_{rev}$ and $W_{irrev}$ elegantly proves that "both a reversible and irreversible adiabatic process can't occur between the same intial and final equilibrium states" as in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/691156/338789) answer, to compare the final pressures/volumes/temperatures requires me to make several cases which is too tedious.  So, I was looking for a more direct approach.

P.S. I'm a high school student. Please answer in simple language and in minute detail.

**Addendum**:Please consider the piston to be massless and the irreversible adiabatic process to be single step.

Comment: Are you also comparing expansion vs compression, or just looking at expansion?

Comment: @ChetMiller Both

Comment: @ChetMiller Also, please assume a massless piston.

Comment: Are you also assuming that the irreversible paths occur at constant external pressure (after an initial sudden pressure decrease or increase)?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, only a single-step irreversible adiabatic process.

Comment: @Boson Your response to Chet's second question indicates that only (a) applies

Comment: Let's see what you've done so far.

Comment: @ChetMiller Should I edit my question?

Comment: Sure.  Let”s see your results.

Comment: Let's see your final equations, and let's see your graphical comparisons.  I would plot temperature ratios, pressure ratios, and volume ratios.  For work, I would plot dimensionless work, $$(1-\frac{T_2}{T_1})$$